# Berkeley DB store is so slow

Tags: c, berkeley-db, solid-state-drive

I am using Berkeley DB to store the data persistently in my program. I tested it on my SSD, my SSD speed is 1.4Gb/s for writing. My progrma for testing the storing speed of DB is shown below (error checking is omitted).

```
const char* db_dir="./.db";
const char* db_name = "node_test_0";

void mk_path(char* dest,const char* prefix,const char* db_name){
    memcpy(dest,prefix,strlen(prefix));
    dest[strlen(prefix)] = '/';
    memcpy(dest+strlen(prefix)+1,db_name,strlen(db_name));
    dest[strlen(prefix)+strlen(db_name)+1] = '\0';
    return;
}

int main() {
    DB* b_db;
    DB_ENV* dbenv;
    int ret;
    int flag = 0;
    DBT key, data;
    char* full_path = NULL;
    if((ret = mkdir(db_dir,S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH)) != 0){
        if(errno != EEXIST){
        }
    }
    full_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(db_dir) + strlen(db_name) + 2);
    mk_path(full_path, db_dir, db_name);
    if ((ret = db_env_create(&dbenv, 0)) != 0) {
        dbenv->err(dbenv, ret, "Environment Created: %s", db_dir);
    }
    if ((ret = dbenv->open(dbenv, db_dir, DB_CREATE|DB_INIT_CDB|DB_INIT_MPOOL|DB_THREAD, 0)) != 0) {
    }

    if((ret = db_create(&b_db,dbenv,flag)) != 0){
    }

    if((ret = b_db->open(b_db, NULL, db_name, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_THREAD|DB_CREATE,0)) != 0){

    }

    struct timeval start_time;
    struct timeval end_time;
    unsigned long e_usec;

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    key.data = "fruit"; 
    key.size = sizeof("fruit"); 
    data.data = "apple"; 
    data.size = sizeof("apple");

    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
    ret = b_db->put(b_db, NULL, &key, &data, 0);
    gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
    e_usec = ((end_time.tv_sec * 1000000) + end_time.tv_usec) - ((start_time.tv_sec * 1000000) + start_time.tv_usec);
    printf("%lu\n", e_usec);

    if (ret == 0) 
        printf("db: %s: key stored.\n", (char *)key.data); 
    else { 
        b_db->err(b_db, ret, "DB->put"); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result is about 23 microseconds. It's much slower than I expected. Does anyone have idea on this? What can I do to make my persistent storage as fast as writing to SSD.

Comment: Saving to a file will *never* be as fast as writing raw data directly to a disk. And on top of that, a database adds at least one layer of abstractions on top of the file, so using a database will also be slower than storing raw data directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

BerkeleyDB does a fsync after write's to ensure that the data on disk is saved. You can stub out the fsync(2) vector (just return 0) if you are willing to live with the consequence of possibly catastrophic data loss (which is acceptable for a temporary, non-persistent, data store using BDB)